# Using TriangulatePoints with SFM with Python

Tags: python, opencv, triangulation

I'm trying to use the built in opencv function TriangulatePoints for multiple views: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.4/d0/dbd/group__triangulation.html#ga211c855276b3084f3bbd8b2d9161dc74.

Using python on linux, does anyone have experience using this function? The website only has the syntax for cpp and in python I don't know how to code it.

My code now:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
point_2D = np.array([[17.4485, 709.7993], [17.4382, 709.8409]])
Proj_Matrices = np.array([ [1037.5, -6.9927, -10.0190, -4780.7], [6.9747, 1043.3, -5.8867, -731.9206], [644.7895, 383.4982, -3231.1], [1036.937, -22.8371, -28.3254, -5607.7], [23.0587, 1043.1, 3.1815, -633.4485], [650.4355, 373.6, -15.3504, -3706.5] ])

OutputArray = np.zeros((3,2))
Points_3D = cv2.sfm.triangulatePoints(point_2D, Proj_Matrices, OutputArray)
```

However, when I run it from the terminal I get the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'sfm.

I installed sfm on my computer using the instructions on the opencv site.

When I omit sfm I get the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'sfm'

I think I get that error since the machine thinks I'm trying to use the previous version of TriangulatePoints.

Examples of opencv code using sfm exist on the opencv website but they are in cpp.

I'm wondering what the syntax for using **TriangulatePoints(with sfm)** is in python? Even in cpp, I don't understand how the output array is an input to the function? Also, if anyone knows how to fix the sfm error I am receiving that would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think in python you need to call it `cv2.triangulatePoints( ... )`, without sfm